# imageupload works in local but does not work in server

Tags: ajax, vb.net, web-services, webmethod, image-upload

I want to upload a image on server.I use ajax and webmethod, It works when I run code in local host but when I upload it in server it does not work.
I guess there are some problems in my webmethod but I could not find it.

```
    function savefile(location, files, method_name) {

        var data = new FormData();
        var webmethod = "../WebService.asmx/" + method-name;


        if (files.length > 0) {
            data.append("UploadedFile", files[0]);
            data.append("location", location);


        }

        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webmethod,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data


        });


    }


     <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
        <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
        Public Function savefile() As String
            Try

                Dim result As String = ""
                Dim pdf As String = ""
                If HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any() Then


                    Dim httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files("UploadedFile")

                    If httpPostedFile IsNot Nothing Then

                        Dim location = HttpContext.Current.Request("location")
                        Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(httpPostedFile.FileName)
                        Dim filename_widthout_extension As String = httpPostedFile.FileName.Substring(0, httpPostedFile.FileName.Length - extension.Length)
                        Dim file_name = httpPostedFile.FileName
                        Dim fileSavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request("location").ToString), filename_widthout_extension + postfix + extension)



                        result = (location + "/" + filename_widthout_extension + extension).ToString.Substring(2)

                        httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath)
                        location = httpPostedFile.FileName
 End If
            Return ""

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  I would suspect that there might be a permission issue writing files to the directory on the server

Comment: No! I put  MsgBox at the beginning of webmethod and I comment all codes of webmethod. I found out the codes of webmethod does not run.I put some alerts in script code and they were shown

Comment: i notice you are accessing this method through `"../WebService.asmx/"`, but which is the url of your page? if the page and the webservice are in the same folder you shouldn't specify the `../` part (the url is relative to the page not the script)

Comment: err, MsgBox in server code will not popup, it's executed in a service. (if you're not in debug of course)

Comment: I have replaced webmethod with handler and it works fine..but I was not successful with webmethod

Comment: but thanks for your answer